# Is there a formal causal model of avoidable admissions?

Tags: hospital, cause-and-effect

I would like to approach modelling the causes of avoidable admissions to a hospital using a Pearlian causal framework (see [Pearl 2009](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjcldGUrtyAAxWZMjQIHTQLDnUQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fftp.cs.ucla.edu%2Fpub%2Fstat_ser%2Fr350.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0OkDcWUq0iUeFt91sUm4fY&opi=89978449) for a terse overview). I read in [Booker & Purdy 2022](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9512436/) that defining what an "avoidable admission" is can be quite difficult, so a source that operationally defines it would be a good starting point.

Are there *any* formal causal models of avoidable admissions?

Comment: The only way I could imagine determining if an admission is avoidable would be to have human clinicians annotate admissions as avoidable or unavoidable manually. Note that you would have to develop a very good annotation guide before hand. I hope you have a big budget.

Comment: @IanCampbell Another approach is to treat the avoidability of an admission as a counterfactual query rather than a variable in the data set. There are still substantial challenges I'm concerned about even with that in view, but that's beyond the scope of my question.